# Change Target Framework Error (MSVSMON.exe)

Tags: vb.net, debugging, visual-studio-2012, frameworks

I started a new application and changed the target framework to v2.0 for Windows XP compatibility but when I run the debugger (with or without code) I get an error saying MSVSMON.exe appears to not be running. I tried restarting the project and even changing the target framework back to v4.5 but I still get the error. How do I fix this?

Comment: don't know if your problem is similar to the one discussed in [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/10452212-c8f7-47d1-ba5b-96350e1bd616/cannot-debug-msvsmonexe-failed-to-start). Might worth a check out.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite old, but in case somebody has the same issue I thought I'll answer it. I changed the platform target to 32bit and debugging worked. Setting it to 64 bit or Any CPU caused the error you are describing. Not really the perfect solution but at least I can debug now.